How to fake hi-poly circular holes using normal maps?
I'd like to learn to use normal maps to make booleans look more hi-poly than they are.
I've attempted to use multiresolution, but it can't work with auto-smooth or copies of the mesh in different subdivisions.
How the geometry looks like:


How I want it to look like using a Normal Map (Mockup):

Note: I will use this skill in places with curved surfaces, oval-shaped holes, and both.

What does multiresolution have to do with any of this?

It was one of the things I used as a way to bevel the curvature with subdivisions, I thought it was going to work for me

I think you should edit the question and explain what you want better. Show more screenshots of what you have as well with topology visible. What do the yellow lines in your mockup represent? What should your desired result look like? Do you have any reference images of the thing you are trying to model?

| What do the yellow lines in your mockup represent? They represent the edges marked with Sharpness

| Do you have any reference images of the thing you are trying to model? I have a page from Sketchfab that has my desired result (Look at the hand holes on the wheels)

The official documentation on the subject

I'm aware of the subject, @TheLabCat. What I want is a more "automated" way to bake circular hole bevels with High poly detail into a low poly surface.

Update: I believe I found a solution

Make the first model, then its texture, and UV Map;
Duplicate it, then set up the Mean Crease on the copy;
Subdivide the copy, and make sure the "Render" amount is in a proper number that gives you the desired amount of bevel;
Select the two objects, where the non-subdivided one is active;
Bake with the "Normal" type, with the "Selected to Active" Checkbox marked;
Adjust the extrusion if the cylindrical part has no normal map
applied.

If everything goes accordingly, you'll get this result


Note: The texture looks low-res due to how big the object actually is, and how "disproportionate" the texture is.
